# I want to create an IF statement usng info from 2 different columns in EXCEL

Tags: excel, if-statement

So i have this: `=IF($A2>=0,"On Time",IF($A2<0,"Past Due"))`
but outcome could be different depending on data in a different column.
How would I write something like `A2<0,"Past Due"` except when `B2=Y`, then `A2<0,"On Time"`?

Comment: =if(or(A2>=0,B2="Y"),"On Time","Past Due")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the or function within the if statement to do what you want.

```
=if(or(A2>=0,B2="Y"),"On Time","Past Due")
```